# No output is being generated by ArcPy's MakeFeatureLayer method

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, filter, feature-class

I have a feature class that I would like to filter by an attribute and write the result to a new feature layer. I can achieve this with a simple one-liner in the R programming language, but I need to translate my workflow into ArcPy and it has been giving me nothing but trouble!

The following example runs without any errors, but no output feature layer is created within the `data/tmp/scratch` directory. Is this file being created somewhere else, or is it not being created at all?

```
# set up environment
import os, sys, arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"data/tmp"))
scratchFolder = arcpy.env.scratchFolder

# define parameters
input_fc = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "data/input.gdb/input_feature_class"))
output_layer = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(scratchFolder, os.path.basename(input_fc)+"_subset.lyrx"))
query = "filter_field = '1'"

# create new layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(input_fc, output_layer, query)
```

Apologies in advance for not providing a reprex. I'm new to ArcPy and would be happy to modify my example if someone can point me towards example data that exists within the ArcPy module.

Comment: In ArcGIS parlance, a "layer" is an object created in the mapping framework for purposes of rendering. Creating a new layer does *not* manifest new data, just controls the display options of existing data. If you want to create a new feature class, you need export the layer as a feature class, or just use FeatureClassToFeatureClaas.

Comment: Thank you for clearing things up with Feature Layers. Switching to `FeatureClassToFeatureClass` is now producing an output for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this file being created somewhere else, or is it not being created at all?

The literal answer to this question is, **"It is being created, but it is not a file."**

The answer you probably want, though, is more like...

The file path that you assigned to `output_layer` is not being used as a file path, but merely as a string identifier for your new layer.  The new layer is not new data, but merely a definition of how to view/filter the data in the existing `input_fc` feature class.

You could have assigned `output_layer = "out_layer"` and it would have worked just as well (and made more sense).

If you do wish to save it as a feature class, you could use the following to do so:

`arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(input_fc, os.path.dirname(output_layer), os.path.basename(output_layer), query)`

(Not tested - just made up off the top of my head.)

Comment: Thank you for the help. `FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion()` is working on my end!

Comment: excellent!  good to hear